# How to refresh DataGridView in active WinForm from another class?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Winform with a DataGridView holding a few table values from API calls to a server database. I want to refresh the table after the servers are polled, so I used a timer to regularly poll the servers. I'm not sure how to get the active WinForm to update it or to replace it because I have one WinForm that is run from the "Program" class and another one that is run from my "PollTimers" class, where the timer configuration and running takes place. Here are my methods, "UpdateTable" is from my "Form1" class and "OnPollEvent" is from "PollTimers".

```
        public void UpdateTable(string id, string status, string ticketStatus)
    {

        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if ((string)row.Cells[2].Value == id)
            {
                row.Cells[3].Value = status;
                row.Cells[4].Value = ticketStatus;
            }
        }
        dataGridView1.Update();
        dataGridView1.Refresh();

    }


        private async void OnPollEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
        Console.WriteLine("updating...");
        foreach (Server server in Polls)
        {
            string json = await call.CallAsync(server.id);
            dynamic convert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
            string ticketStatus = await call.TicketStatusAsync(server.id);
            if (convert.status != "online")
            {
                Polls.Remove(server);
                RePolls.Add(server, 0);

            }
            f.UpdateTable(server.id, convert.status, ticketStatus);

        }
        Console.WriteLine("updated.");
    }
```

Comment: If the DGV was bound to a DataSource all you'd have to do is refresh that datasource (which takes 1 line of code) - no need to iterate rows or ping pong with data.  Also, the `Update()` and `Refresh()` methods probably do not do what you think they do - they have to do with making the control redraw/repaint - nothing to do with data.

Comment: Use a BindingSource to bind the DataTable to the DGV: set the `BindingSource.DataSource` to your DataTable, set the `DGV.DataSource` to the BindingSource. When you receive new data, update the DataTable. The BindingSource will notify the DGV of the update and the *visual* data will be updated automatically.